# Is there a formula to relate the axial length of a nozzle expander with its radius?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know the inlet, throat and outlet areas for a nozzle expander. Is there a formula to know its axial length? Something like L= f(A) = f(D).

Comment: The lowest loss is with about a 6 degree angle... but length can be appreciable...

Comment: What about 20 degrees?

Comment: Why not 70 degrees...

Comment: Are there any analytical expressions to calculate that loss as a function of the angle? Or the isentropic efficiency as a function of the angle.

Comment: Probably in a textbook somewhere.